# How to remove the double quotes of a variable in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

The API authentication is denied as the value of $login_token variable that I pass in the curl command is enclosed with double quotes during the execution.

**Code**

```
set -x
login_token="eUsadjb@dsi-0nknhsnc"
API_Response=$(curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer '$login_token 'https://example.com')
set +x
```

**Curl Response in Debug Mode**

```
++ curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer "eUsadjb@dsi-0nknhsnc"'
+API_Response='Authorization has been denied for this request. Please use a valid access token.'
```

As you can notice that the login_token value is embedded with double quotes when passed as a variable and this causes the failure. The value of login_token variable should be passed without quotes as it is. Suppose, if I pass the value of login_token directly in the curl command, then the authentication is successful.

**Direct Value - Authentication Success**

```
API_Response=$(curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer eUsadjb@dsi-0nknhsnc' 'https://example.com')
```

How can I pass the value of login_token variable without quotes in curl command?

FYI, I tried the following method as well, but it doesn't work

```
login_token="eUsadjb@dsi-0nknhsnc"
API_Response=$(curl -X POST --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer $login_token" "https://example.com")
```

Comment: `login_token="eUsadjb@dsi-0nknhsnc"` does NOT embed double-quotes within `login_token`. Try it, `echo $login_token`. The double-quotes come from `curl`. I would check for an answer already on the site. I'll look, I don't use `curl` much so I don't have the answer on the tip of my tongue.

Comment: [How Remove Quotes, Unwanted Data From JSON String of CURL Response PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51340943/3422102) looks related.

Comment: Your last attempt should've worked. Unless we see curl's verbose output, it'll be impossible to rule out.

Comment: What's the `set -x` output from `login_token="eUsadjb@dsi-0nknhsnc"`? If everything's normal, it should show `+ login_token=eUsadjb@dsi-0nknhsnc` because the double-quotes aren't actually doing anything.

Comment: which sh did you use.I tried bash and zsh.all is ok.`++ curl -X POST --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer eUsadjb@dsi-0nknhsnc' https://example.com`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I get the login_token from the response of another API and that value is embedded with double quotes which goes unnoticed in the naked eyes. It's my mistake. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: So you are saying what you actually have is `login_token='"eUsadjb@dsi-0nknhsnc"'` then. In that case just trim the quotes with `login_token="${login_token//\"/}"`